# Selector problem with dynamic list elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

Please check the code demo for easy understanding.

When the list element is displayed as two columns, the following method can be used to implement the page responsive design.

```css
.test {
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 justify-content:space-between;
}
.test div {
 width:calc(50% - 30px);
 padding:10px 0 10px 10px;
 margin:8px;
 background:#ffc107;
}
.test div:nth-last-of-type(1):nth-child(odd) {
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
</div>
```

When the list exceeds two columns, the above method is no longer applicable.

For example, the following list has four columns. How do select the odd elements of the last row?

```css
.test {
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 justify-content:space-between;
}
.test div {
 width:calc(25% - 30px);
 padding:10px 0 10px 10px;
 margin:8px;
 background:#ffc107;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
</div>
```

Is there a CSS selector solution for this problem?

Comment: If you _know_ that there are four columns, just nth-last-child(2) and nth-last-child(4) (for an even number of items) will do. But that's not what you mean, right?

Comment: @MrLister I need to select the odd elements in the last line of the list (the list contents are dynamic if they exist), that is, the first and third elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exchange your `width:` declaration for a `flex:` declaration:

```
flex: 1 0 calc(25% - 30px);
```

`flex` is a short-hand declaration which declares:

- `flex-grow`
- `flex-shrink`
- `flex-basis`

The last value (`flex-basis`) declares the default width of an element, all else being equal.

If there are more or fewer elements in the last row, then `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` indicate how much those elements should grow or shrink relative to the space that needs to be filled.

**Working Example:**

```css
.test {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content:space-between;
}
.test div {
 flex: 1 0 calc(25% - 30px);
 padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
 margin: 8px;
 background: #ffc107;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, it is very useful!